# C Error Open O_RDWR on Read-Only Flash NAND MTD0

Tags: c, file-io, readonly, flash-memory

I have made a code that read data from flash Nand (without filesystem).

```
fd = open("/dev/mtd0", O_RDONLY)
```

It works, then I want to try to read write it..
So I change the code to:

```
fd = open("/dev/mtd0", O_RDWR)
```

But It returns `-1`, means can not open. But for others MTD, it works.

Then I see `cat /proc/mtd` said that MTD0 is `RO` and the other is `RW` (i think it's Read-Only and Read-Write)

I tried to use `MEMUNLOCK`

```
ioctl(fd, MEMUNLOCK, &mtdLockInfo)
```

Because it needs `fd`, needs `open` so i use `O_RDONLY` not `O_RDWR`(return `-1`).

But it returns error `Bad file description`. It must be because of `O_RDONLY`,, have to use `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`.

Is there any way to UNLOCK this MTD0, or to write on it without unlock it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to change the partition of my NAND flash in the Device Tree Source(DTS).

There's an read-only option.
But, I only  changed their size.

ANd it's done.. My NAND flash can be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

The operation is likely being forbidden by the kernel driver for your device. It's likely that your device is actually read-only or marked as such by the driver.

Comment: so.. is there any option to unlock it? without modifying the kernel?

Comment: check dmesg for any relevant messages about that device.  What is the physical hardware?  Which driver is picking it up?  Are there any parameters being passed to the module?

Comment: (ST Micro NAND 256MiB 3,3V 8-bit),, I'm using Linux Embedded